# Is there a way I can Extract data from SAP GUI to Excel in the background?

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I am trying to extract data from SAP GUI to Excel in the background using Excel VBA. I am new to this, kindly bear with me.

I have a code that is running fine now, which requires the username and the password and also the Transaction code and table name of the table that I need the data from. I am able to do this using SAP GUI Scripting. The only issue is that whenever this code is triggered, the macro shows it on the screen whatever the code is doing.

Is there a way in which all the steps that are being performed can be put in the background and only the output can be shown? I tried `Application.screenupdating = false` method of excel but since it is not working.

I am extracting a table say ABC from SAP and storing it in a csv file first and then using text to column method to pull the data from CSV file to excel. Whenever I run the macro, the entire operation starting from logging into the SAP, entering username and password,using tcode SE16, entering the table screen and so on can be seen on the screen. and once the extraction is complete, it goes back to the Excel screen where I ran the macro. It is difficult to take a snapshot as it is too fast and one Screenshot would not be able to explain it.

Here is the snapshot of the final output: 
[image: 1]

Comment: `the macro shows it on the screen` what screen? SAP or VBA or Excel? How it is look like? Give the screenshot

Comment: `and only the output shown` what means output? give the expected result screen

Comment: Hi,
I am extracting a table say ABC from SAP and storing it in a csv file first and then using text to column method to pull the data from CSV file to excel.

Whenever I run the macro, the entire operation starting from logging into the SAP, entering username and password,using tcode SE16, entering the table screen and so on can be seen on the screen. and once the extraction is complete, it goes back to the Excel screen where I ran the macro.
It is difficult to take a snapshot as it is too fast and one Screenshot would not be able to explain it.

Comment: https://imgur.com/W6W5D1V

Here is the snapshot of the final output

Comment: `where I ran the macro` if you run the macro manually, it will be impossible to make it background. Without the screenshots it will be hard to guess what window you'd like to suppress. Try making screenshot in burst mode if the windows are going too fast

Comment: Hi,

Please check if you are able to view the video in this link.
https://web.microsoftstream.com/video/ef14703d-98d4-4720-a486-fcb07f1445d7

Comment: If not that link, try this one.
https://vimeo.com/user107962920/review/387650500/12262997ec

It shows how the code extracts the SAP table data when triggered by the macro

Comment: the first link throws *You can't sign in here with a personal account. Use your work or school account instead.* and the second link throws *Sorry, we couldn’t find that page*. Upload to https://streamable.com/ instead

Comment: http://www.streamable.com/ - this link is not opening in my system.
Try the vimeo link, it is working for a friend of mine as well.